# Trying to count the number of character in a string

Tags: mysql

I've created this MySQL function to count the number of characters (`str`) in a string(`search`):

```
drop function if exists find_str;

delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION `FIND_STR`(search VARCHAR(255), str CHAR(1))
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
SELECT ROUND (   
        (
            CHAR_LENGTH(search)
            - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE ( search, str, "") ) 
        ) / CHAR_LENGTH(str)
    ) AS count INTO @count;
return @count;
END//

delimiter ;
```

If str is space, the function always return null, but I'm not sure why.

```sql
find_str('Hello', 'l') => 2 // correct
find_str('Hi there', ' ') => null // incorrect, it's supposed to be 1
find_str('Hi there', space(1)) => null // also incorrect, it's supposed to be 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the definition of `CHAR(..)`.  It includes trailing blanks to fill out the space indicated.  But the actual string is does not have any trailing spaces.  So `' '` becomes `''`.

So, change from `str CHAR(1)` to `str VARCHAR(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It must be one of the numerous quirks of MySQL; apparently `CHAR_LENGTH(str)` returns 0 if `str` is a function argument with the value of `' '`. You probably don't have [`ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero) enabled, hence NULL output.

May be one of the MySQL experts here can explain the behaviour.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=057cc0ec96418ebe1b1a0dca0288cc6e)

Comment: This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a811c22e647d71af236a0b981431783) explains... The problem source is in "safe datatype" system and implicit data types convertion. Intermediate format is VARCHAR/TEXT, so all trailing spaces are removed. Even if the output datatype is CHAR(x) - [fiddle2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2700b802c173da78a817c42be4a51427). And `transmit_char(CAST(' 1 ' AS CHAR(3)))` will not help...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need in:

1. ROUND - the division result must be integer (ever it would be non-integer, it will be rounded due to output data type)
2. SELECT - the result may be calculated in RETURN immediately
3. Compound statement - as a result of (2)
4. Delimiter reassign - as a result of (3)

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_chars_count;

CREATE FUNCTION get_chars_count (str_to_search VARCHAR(255), char_search_for VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
RETURN (CHAR_LENGTH(str_to_search)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(str_to_search,char_search_for,'')))/CHAR_LENGTH(char_search_for);
```